# Node.js pm2 Optional Chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

Optional Chaining is a great feature and I'm using it. When I tested my code on node and nodemon the codes are working but when I run it on pm2 this error shows.
var dude = res?.param?.params[0]
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: What version of `pm2` and `node` are you using?

Comment: @SamGomena pm2 - 4.5.5 node -v15.8.0